# How to send an API request and trigger recomposition at the same time?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-multiplatform

I have a Kotlin application using Compose Multiplatform for the front-end and Ktor for the backend. Let's say for example, this app allows users to make a list of their favourite animals. The backend provides REST API endpoints to add or delete an animal from their favourites list. On the frontend, we would like to allow the user to add and delete animals from the list, and have it immediately reflected as a change in UI. I want to keep the front end appearance and backend data in sync. A user's data is only ever modified by themselves however, so we don't need to support realtime updates.

We have currently been using a mutable state list to hold the list on the front end. Then to update it, we have to write two seperate lines, one for the frontend code and one to make the API request to the backend.

```
val myAnimals = mutableStateListOf(panda, giraffe, horse)
myAnimals.add(dog) // update the front end to show the dog in the list
api.post('/my_animals', dog) // call the API to update the database
```

I would like to incorporate this into one line to simplify it and prevent errors since they will always be used together. Ideally, it would be nice to call `myAnimals.add` and have it automatically call the API while still triggering recomposition. How can I go about this?

Comment: Hey here is a example you can do this:

Comment: @Vivek please add suggestion or document link here

Comment: Hi, you mentioned you'd like to call `add` and automatically call the API to prevent errors. What about you call the API first and wait for the response. If the request is successful, you can bravely update your list, or even bether, fetch the updated data from the API to update your local data. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I think you should only display the updated list after you are sure that the newly added animal was successfully stored to the backend.

One possible structure to achieve this is by using a ViewModel, a Repository, and a Service.

If you are using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for sending the REST requests and [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/compose/) for dependency injection, you will define a Service class like this:

```
interface AnimalService {

    @GET("animal")
    suspend fun loadAnimals(): List<Animal>

    @POST("animal")
    suspend fun saveAnimal(animal: Animal): Void

}
```

Next, define a Repository class that manages the API calls:

```
class AnimalRepository(
    private val animalService: AnimalService  // injected by Koin
) {

    suspend fun addAnimal(animal: Animal): List<Animal> {
        animalService.saveAnimal(animal)
        return animalService.loadAnimals()
    }
}
```

Then define a ViewModel to call the Repository functions:

```
class AnimalViewModel(
    private val animalRepository: AnimalRepository  // injected by Koin
) : ViewModel() {

    
    var animalList: List<WatchProvider> by mutableStateOf(listOf())

    fun addAnimal(animal: Animal) {
         viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                animalList = animalRepository.addAnimal(animal)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // This Exception will be thrown if POST or GET failed
                Log.d("Network Exception", e.stackTraceToString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you can call this ViewModel function from your Composable:

```
MyComposable(
    animalViewModel: AnimalViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    Button( 
        onclick = { animalViewModel.addAnimal(new Animal("Dog")) }
    ) {
        Text(text = "ADD ANIMAL")
    }
}
```